# Absolute convergence of an integral

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds, absolute-convergence

Does the integral
$$ 
\int_0^\infty \left| \frac{\cos(2x)+x \sin(2x)-1}{x^3} \right| dx
$$
converge?

---

The obvious upper bound
$$
\left| \frac{\cos(2x)+x \sin(2x)-1}{x^3} \right| \leq \frac{|\cos(2x)|+|x \sin(2x)| + 1}{|x^3|} \leq \frac{2+|x|}{|x^3|}
$$
does not work, since $\int_0^\infty \frac{2+x}{x^3} dx$ is not convergent.

Mathematica says this integral is convergent. How can I find a convergent upper bound? Thanks.

Comment: Hint $$\int \frac{x \sin (2 x)+\cos (2 x)-1}{x^3} \, dx=\frac{\sin ^2(x)}{x^2}+C$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the integral up into
$$
\int^\infty_0 \left \lvert \frac{\cos(2x)+x\sin(2x)-1}{x^3} \right \rvert = \underbrace{\int^1_0 \left \lvert \frac{\cos(2x)+x\sin(2x)-1}{x^3} \right \rvert~\mathrm{d}x}_{=:A} + \underbrace{\int^\infty_1 \left \lvert \frac{\cos(2x)+x\sin(2x)-1}{x^3} \right \rvert~\mathrm{d}x}_{=:B}
$$
Now prove
$$
\lim_{x \downarrow 0} \left \lvert \frac{\cos(2x)+x\sin(2x)-1}{x^3} \right \rvert = 0
$$
using e.g. l'Hopital. Therefore $A< \infty$, because the integrand stays bounded on a compact set.

For $B$ you can now use that $\displaystyle\int^\infty_1 \frac{2 + x}{x^3}~\mathrm{d}x$ does indeed converge. So $B< \infty$.